# How can I limit total concurrent subscriber connections to a ZeroMQ publisher endpoint?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

When building a pub-sub service using ZeroMQ on a Linux system, is there any way to enforce concurrent subscriber limits?

For example, I might want to create a ZeroMQ publisher service on a resource-limited system, and want to prevent overloading the system by setting a limit of, say, 100 concurrent connections to the tcp publisher endpoint.  After that limit is reached, all subsequent connection attempts from ZeroMQ subscribers would fail.

I understand ZeroMQ doesn't provide notifications about connect/disconnect, but I've been looking for socket options that might allow such limits -- so far, no luck.

Or is this something that should be handled at some other level, perhaps within the protocol?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, ZeroMQ is a Can-Do messaging framework:

Besides the trivial Formal Communication Pattern Framework elements ( the library primitives ), the strongest powers behind the ZeroMQ is the ability to develop one's own messaging system(s).

In your case, it is enough to enrich the scene with a few additional things ... a **`SUB`**-process -> **`PUB`**-process **message-flow-channel**, so as to allow `PUB`-side process to count a number of **`SUB`**-process instances concurrently connected and to allow for a disconnect ( a step delegated rather "back" to a **`SUB`**-process side suicside move, as the classical **`PUB`**-process, intentionally, has no instrumentation to manage subscriptions ) once a limit is dynamically achieved.

Plus add some dynamics for the inter-node signalling to start re-counting and/or to equip the **`SUB`**-process side(s) with a self-advertising mechanism to push-keepAliveSIG-s to the `PUB`-side and expect this signalling to be a weak and informative-only indication as there are many real-world collisions, where decentralised node simply fail to deliver a "guaranteed-delivery" message(s) and a well designed, distributed, low-latency, high-performance system has to cope well with this reality and have the self-healing state-recovery policies designed and in-built into own behaviour.

[image]

*( Fig. courtesy imatix/ZeroMQ )*

The ZeroMQ library can be thought of as a **very powerful LEGO-tool-box** for designing cool distributed systems, than a ready-made / batteries-included, stiff, *quasi-**solution**-for-just-a-few-academic-cases* ( well, it might be considered such, but just for some no-brainer's life, while our lives are much more colourful & teasing, aren't they ? )

### So, "How to?"

Worth, definitely worth a few days to read the both of Pieter Hintjens' books & a few weeks for shifting one's mind to start designing with the ZeroMQ full-powers on one's side.

With just a few Python add-on habits ( a `zmq.Context()` early-setup, and not forgetting a **`finally:`**  `aContext.term()` )

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that I'm aware of to *configure* ZMQ to limit connections automatically... however, you have other options to accomplish what you're looking for.  Perhaps the "traditional" way to accomplish this is with a second set of "network communication" sockets... perhaps `REQ/REP` from subscriber to publisher, asking for permission to connect.

You also have the option, depending on your version of ZMQ (and I've never used it and I can't find it in 5 minutes of searching, so I don't know how recent your version must be) to use `XPUB/XSUB` sockets, which *can* accomplish bi-directional communication.  You can connect with XSUB, send a subscribe request, then receive a positive or negative response (you might have to play with your subscriber topics to communicate directly with just the single subscriber, I'm not sure), and react accordingly.

Either way, you'll be allowing a connection of some sort between the two systems and then either allowing it or terminating it depending on the situation.  This could be less than completely ideal since you'll have to carve out a little overhead to handle connections that you'll be refusing... let's say you're saturated at 100 clients and all of a sudden get 100 new subscribe requests... you may or may not be able to cope with that sort of burst traffic.

You can test out the overhead in alternative communication mediums... like you could publish a webservice that indicates subscriber status that a client could check first, but that may not be any better to have clients connecting that way.

If you're absolutely at the limit of your resources, you'll have to set up a second server to handle subscriber status:

- Server 1 is your publisher.  You could set it up with a `PUB` socket and a `REP` socket.
- Server 2 is your status server.  It has a `REQ` socket.  Have it subscribe to something like "system-status" or some such thing as that.  It will also have your mechanism for communicating with new subscribers, be that a ZMQ socket or a web service or whatever else.
- A client will request status from your status server.  The status server will send a request to your publisher, which will increment it's subscriber count and reply with success, or keep its subscriber count and reply with failure. This success or failure will be communicated back to the subscriber, which will use that information to connect or not.
- Disconnections will have to be communicated in a similar way... and you'll have to use some sort of heartbeating round-robin to confirm clients weren't a victim of catastrophic failure.

This will allow your publisher to make intelligent choices about whether it has resources or not.  If you just want to set a static number, you don't even need the connection between the status server and the publisher, you can just keep count on the status server... but just to ensure the overall health of the network then it's probably best not to go that simplistic route.

Anyway, those are just some ideas to accomplish what you're looking for.  ZMQ gives you options with which to craft your solutions moreso than actual solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer -- the XPUB/XSUB approach seems most reasonable at first glance, for the kinds of scenarios I'm considering.